# How can I extract data from multiple text and save result to JSON?

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have text from log file with format like this:

```
DEBUG: {\"id\":12311,\"pool_num\":\"4125441212441893\",\"full_name\":\"john doe\",\"mobile\":\"000000\","image_1\":\"upload\\/d7379280d549499dd9c948341298703ee.jpeg\",\"image_2\":\"upload\\/4a190fb8941a3d746cff01aa945b.jpeg\",\"image_3\":\"upload\\/3afd55aebb4d1461a4e15b9ac335dd92380.jpeg\"}
DEBUG: {\"id\":12312,\"pool_num\":\"89451222214511221\",\"full_name\":\"jane doe\",\"mobile\":\"000000\","image_1\":\"upload\\/d7379280d5494asdasd9c948341298123.jpeg\",\"image_2\":\"upload\\/4a190fb89asd123746cff01aa945b.jpeg\",\"image_3\":\"upload\\/3afd55aebb4dadasd15b9ac335dd9236661.jpeg\"}
DEBUG: {\"id\":12313,\"pool_num\":\"12312345612312312\",\"full_name\":\"smith doe\",\"mobile\":\"000000\","image_1\":\"upload\\/d7379280d549499dd9c948341298701551.jpeg\",\"image_2\":\"upload\\/123easfdsdagdfhdf213432123123.jpeg\",\"image_3\":\"upload\\/3afd55aebb4d1461a4e15b9ac335dd92380.jpeg\"}
DEBUG: {\"id\":12314,\"pool_num\":\"82123423444112345\",\"full_name\":\"adam doe\",\"mobile\":\"000000\","image_1\":\"upload\\/d7379280d549499dd9c9483412987666.jpeg\",\"image_2\":\"upload\\/asfda1234235we3rtsdasdasdah456.jpeg\",\"image_3\":\"upload\\/3afd55aebb4d1461a4e15b9ac335dd94216.jpeg\"}
```

Currently I can extract some data with this regex:

```
\b(?:pool_num|full_name|image_1|image_2|image_3)\\\":\\\"([^\"]+)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ZmXaVl/1

but the final text contains `"\\"` and not clean yet.

**Question**

I want to extract clean value from `pool_num`, `full_name`, `image_1`, `image_2` and `image_3` and save to `.txt` file with JSON format.

My expected output is :

```
[
    {
        "pool_num" : 4125441212441893,
        "full_name" : "john doe",
        "image_1" : "d7379280d549499dd9c948341298703ee.jpeg",
        "image_2" : "4a190fb8941a3d746cff01aa945b.jpeg",
        "image_3" : "3afd55aebb4d1461a4e15b9ac335dd92380.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "pool_num" : 89451222214511221,
        "full_name" : "jane doe",
        "image_1" : "d7379280d5494asdasd9c948341298123.jpeg",
        "image_2" : "4a190fb89asd123746cff01aa945b.jpeg",
        "image_3" : "3afd55aebb4dadasd15b9ac335dd9236661.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "pool_num" : 12312345612312312,
        "full_name" : "smith doe",
        "image_1" : "d7379280d549499dd9c948341298701551.jpeg",
        "image_2" : "123easfdsdagdfhdf213432123123.jpeg",
        "image_3" : "3afd55aebb4d1461a4e15b9ac335dd92380.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "pool_num" : 82123423444112345,
        "full_name" : "adam doe",
        "image_1" : "d7379280d549499dd9c9483412987666.jpeg",
        "image_2" : "asfda1234235we3rtsdasdasdah456.jpeg",
        "image_3" : "3afd55aebb4d1461a4e15b9ac335dd94216.jpeg"
    }
]
```

How do I get the desired output with the best Python approach?

Comment: It seems like the log file is already json-like. Wouldn't it be simpler to do something like `json.loads(line.split()[1])`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo The original file is not clean. It contain other raw error log from server such as PHP error and other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution that extracts the lines that start with 'DEBUG: ' from the log and then gets the json section of the line and imports it as suggested by @Tomerikoo's comment.

This produces the expected output format as listed in the question.

This solution is dependent on the lines being preceded with 'DEBUG: '.  It could be adjusted to parse lines with additional prefixes too.

If this approach will work for the problem, then it will be more resilient that some of the regular-expresssion based solutions.

```
import json
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

    mydata = []
    lines = log.split("\n")
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("DEBUG: {"):
            json_string = line.split("DEBUG: ")[1]
            mydata.append(json.loads(json_string))
    
    pp.pprint(mydata)
```